# Can't resolve local hostnames when DNS server is set to google's (Win 10)

Tags: networking, dns, ip, ping

I was trying to access the public folders on my laptop (`backup-pc`), connected to the same LAN as my desktop, but it kept giving me an error about wrong credentials. Digging into the problem, I  discovered with a `ping backup-pc` that it resolved to 127.0.0.1, while the actual IP was 192.168.1.95, so it obviously couldn't resolve the name.

Here's some results from what I attempted on the desktop:

1. With the IPv4 properties of my network card set to **Obtain an IP address automatically** and manually setting the DNS addresses to google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), pinging the hostnames resolves to 127.0.0.1, but explicitly pinging the IP works. Using `nslookup backup-pc` gives *Non-authoritative answer: Name: backup-pc.homenet.telecomitalia.it Address:  127.0.0.1*
2. When setting the IPv4 properties to **Use the following ip address** with a static address and manually setting the DNS addresses to google's (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), pinging the hostnames resolves to their true IP. Using `nslookup backup-pc` gives *dns.google isn't able to find backup-pc: Non-existent domain*
3. When setting the IPv4 properties to **Obtain an IP address automatically** and **Obtain DNS server address automatically**, pinging the hostnames resolves to their true IP, but Using `nslookup backup-pc` gives a timeout on the response.

I tried doing the same exact things on my laptop as well, trying to contact another pc, and it gives the same results.

I'm using Win 10 1909.
Any help is appreciated, I'd like to know what's going on here.

Comment: You need to find why `backup-pc` resolves to `127.0.0.1`. Check the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` for a redirection rule.

Comment: Everything is commented in that file, so I don't think it does anything in this matter.

Comment: This might perhaps be caused by some installed product, because it's weird...

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's not caused by a third party software, because as I said I tried the same exact step in my laptop, which is brand new, and it was the same.

Comment: Ping is not the best tool to resolve resolution issues. Nslookup is the better tool. You may turn on exhaustive debugging mode of NSlookup, this will display detailed information of name resolving process. Open Command Prompt on client ,type nslookup and type set d2 .Then type backup-pc.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really expert enough to interpret the result: https://pastebin.com/6iAeiDgJ